# Image slider not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make Image slider with 3 images,What I want is when I click on next button next image should appear at a time only one li should be visible

I tried it with index value I want to show li as per the index value mentioned
Here is code

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="thediv">
<li><img src="images/1.jpg" width="620" height="320" /></li>
<li><img src="images/2.jpg" width="620" height="320" /></li>
<li><img src="images/3.jpg" width="620" height="320" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<a href="" id="next">Next</a>
<a href="" id="prev">Previous</a>
```

Here is [fiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/124rjpb2/1/) for better understanding

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing all 3 images when clicking Next because you loop through them all and call show().  But since you have your ul height/width defined along with overflow:hidden, you are not seeing the images when they are shown.  To demonstrate, remove the ".container ul{ width:620px; overflow:hidden; height:320px;}" style and then click Next.

I would simplify your approach with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#next").click(function(){
          var next = $(".thediv li:visible").next();
          next.show().prev().hide();        
    });

      $("#prev").click(function(){
          var prev = $(".thediv li:visible").prev();
          prev.show().next().hide();       
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6xt79xwt/21/

Comment: Perfect Brady,Thank you so much :) I am learning jquery so just was trying to do this slider thanks again